# JQUERY Callback function

Tags: jquery

I AM NEW TO JQUERY

If I'm running the following code the show callback function is repeating twice

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".flip").click(function(){
            $(".panel").show("slow",function(){console.log('---');});
        });
    });
```

```css
    .flip {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #e5eecc;
        border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
    }
    
    .panel {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #e5eecc;
        border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
        padding: 50px;
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
    <div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
    <div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
```

whereas if i write the code as the following the console is occuring once

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".flip").click(function(){
            $(".panel").show("slow",console.log('---'));
        });
    });
```

```css
    .flip {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #e5eecc;
        border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
    }
    
    .panel {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #e5eecc;
        border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
        padding: 50px;
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
    <div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
    <div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
```

can anyone please explain me the reason

Answer (score 0):

When you execute:

```
    $(".panel").show("slow",function(){console.log('---');});
```

you are passing the function as 2nd parameter to `.show`. This will get executed for all `.panel`s and hence `---` is getting logged twice.

Whereas when you execute:

```
    $(".panel").show("slow",console.log('---'));
```

first `console.log('---')` gets executed (and `---` gets logged in console once) and it's return value (which would be `undefined`) gets passed as 2nd parameter to `.show`. Which is equivalent of calling:

```
    $(".panel").show("slow");
```

Hence `console.log` doesn't get executed for each `.panel` and you get to see it only once.